# What is different between onValue and doAction in BaconJS?

Tags: bacon.js

`onValue` "subscribes a given handler function to event stream. Function will be called for each new value in the stream. [It] is the simplest way to assign a side-effect to a stream."

On  the other hand, `doAction` "returns a stream/property where the function f is executed for each value, before dispatching to subscribers."

It sounds like these both just execute a function on each value in a stream. What is different between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `doAction` returns the same stream, allowing you to chain side-effects, while `onValue` is a subscribe-like function (and thus returns an unsubscribe function).

[I had intended to ask this question for real, and then realized the answer as I began to write it down. In case anyone else finds themselves in a similar situation, perhaps this will save them a few minutes.]

Answer (score 4):

The big difference is that `onValue` subscribes to the stream, `doAction` does not. If there are no subscribers, the function inside `doAction` never gets called.

```
var numbers1 = Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])
numbers1.doAction(function(number) {
    alert("doAction Number " + number) // This never gets called
})


var numbers2 = Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])
numbers2.onValue(function(number) {
    alert("onValue Number " + number) // This gets called
})

var numbersBoth = Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])
numbersBoth
  .doAction(function(number) { console.log(number) }) // gets called
  .onValue(function(number) {
    // Do something with number
  })
```

In practice I only use `doAction` for debugging. If you want to split your side effects to separate functions, you can add multiple `onValue` handlers (except for synchronous streams, but they can be made async with a simple `.delay(0)`)